# When I mouse over on out side of div tag icon is getting blinking

Tags: html, css

This is the link for view : http://jsfiddle.net/mQsWc/10/

I have a text strings in value column these are editable items. For indication I used pencil icon after text string.
Problem is if I move mouse around white spaced area(right side of the text string), pencil icon getting flashy(blinking).

Comment: I hope you'll got answers, I've just a suggestion, _avoid_ use of `<div>` tags in `<td>`

Comment: But it is not fixing my issue.

Comment: Thats why its just a sugesstion..:)

Answer (score 2):

Instead

```
<div class="ghostPencil">some number</div>
```

Write

```
<span class="ghostPencil">some number</span>
```

And the blinking will go away

Edit:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mQsWc/15/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: well if i mouse over on a text or white space icon should be visible beside the text.

Comment: This is what i am looking for. But if some data was not editable so I dont want to show icon for that how can we do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working fiddle without blinking.

Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mQsWc/25/

Comment: if i mouse over on a text or white space icon should be beside the text.

Comment: Check the updated fiddle. Hope it will help you works fine in chrome & FF.

Comment: No need to mention width:100%; and float:left for .ghostPencil

Answer (score 1):

I'm sending two methods for fix the bug. I hope they will help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/mQsWc/22/

http://jsfiddle.net/mQsWc/24/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mQsWc/27/  You have to add css(.noHover) for the td. I have applied two td's for first two rows.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `div`s are transparent, and the pointer hit target alternates between the div and its container `td`. To avoid this, I suggest that you associate the editing capabilities and the UI feedback with `td` rather than `div`.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem.. it will remove the blinking effect

```
.ghostPencil {
       width:100%;
    }
```

edit

Or if u want the pencil to appear on hover of `td` then give the parent td of .ghostPencil a class suppose .parent and use the following code

```
.parent:hover .ghostpencil{
        background:url("icon_pencil.png") no-repeat right; 
    padding-right:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
}
```

as suggested by Alexander

Comment: pencil icon is getting end of the td. not beside the text

Comment: well if u want the pencil to appear only on hover of text and not on hover of white space then use "<span>" instead of "<div>" and remove {wdith:100%}

Comment: if i mouse over on a text or white space icon should be beside the text.