# Why does background flicker on hover

Tags: css, flicker

I have the HTML and CSS below. When I hover the image it's opacity goes to zero and a background colour appears while the text goes from `display:none` to `block`. But why is there flickering when hovering the text? I have tried setting `backface-visibility:hidden` on all elements but it does not remove the flicker.

It happens in current Firefox & Chrome and IE11.

Here is [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/hibou/pen/pyEjqY) of the problem

```
<div class="project-card">
<a href="#"><img  src="http://s13.postimg.org/tiwekrks7/dummy_small_1.jpg" height="250" width="380"></a>
<div class="project-caption">
<div class="pc-name">Absolut Vodka</div>
<div class="pc-type">Bottle</div>
<div class="pc-task">Fancy text</div>
</div>
</div>

.project-card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 32%;
  background-color: #0a3837;
}
.project-card p,
.project-card a,
.project-card img {
  margin: 0;
}
.project-card a {
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}
.project-card a:hover {
  opacity: 0.1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.project-card a:hover + .project-caption {
  display: block;
}

.project-caption {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.pc-name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.pc-type,
.pc-task {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Same reason as here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11071917/1139697. As soon as you hover over `a`, `.project-caption` gets shown, thus you don't hover over `a` anymore, thus `.project-caption` gets hidden, thus you hover over `a` again …

Comment: Yea Zeta is correct, backface-visibility has nothing to do with it, you should  remove that.

Comment: @zeta thanks! But I may be daft, because I fail to understand why the same does not apply when I hover `.project-card` rather than `a`? Has it to with `a` being a child of  `.project-card` whereas it is a sibling of `.project-caption` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution based on what Zeta said :

**HTML**

```
<div class="project-card">
  <a href="#"><img  src="http://s13.postimg.org/tiwekrks7/dummy_small_1.jpg" height="250" width="380"></a>
  <div class="project-caption">
    <div class="pc-name">Absolut Vodka</div>
    <div class="pc-type">Bottle</div>
    <div class="pc-task">Fancy text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.project-card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 32%;
  background-color: #0a3837;
}
.project-card p,
.project-card a,
.project-card img {
  margin: 0;
}
.project-card a {
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}
.project-card:hover > a{
  opacity: 0.1;
}
.project-card:hover > a + .project-caption {
  display: block;
}

.project-caption {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.pc-name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.pc-type,
.pc-task {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

And the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rf09bsse/

Comment: I'll add a snippet to this answer. Adrien's code above worked great for all browsers and operating systems I tested execpt for Chrome on Windows 8.1. The opacity change on `a` did not affect its child `img`. I had to add `.project-card img {opacity: inherit;}` for the image to change opacity and the background color to appear. In Adrien's fiddle it was not the case, but on my development site it was the case and I can't pin down why that would be. But anyway, if someone has the same issue, have a look at opacity inheritance.